# Render Unicode (Hex) characters in PDF file using ITextRenderer

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf with Spring boot, I am generating PDF file from Thymeleaf template using ITextRenderer, I have some Unicode (HEX) value to display currency symbols but it does't render Unicode characters

I have taken currency symbol Unicode from this URL [Currency Unicode reference](https://www.ip2currency.com/currency-symbol)

Here below is my Java code to generate PDF from Thymeleaf template

```
String html = templateEngine.process("templates/Quote", context);
FileOutputStream os = null;
File parentDirectory=null;
try {
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(quoteNumber+".pdf");
    BufferedOutputStream bs= new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(bs,true);
    outputStream.close();
    Assert.notNull("greeting", "The templateName can not be null");
    final Context ctx = new Context();
    String processedHtml = templateEngine.process("greeting", ctx);
    String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();             

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("File not found >>> ",e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("IO Exception >>> ",e);
}          
finally {
    if (os != null) {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { /*ignore*/ }
    }
}
```

Please help me to display currency symbols in generated PDF

Comment: You have posted an excerpt from your codebase, but it doesn't help to understand the problem at all. The closest name to iText in your code is `ITextRenderer `, but this is not an iText class, this is your class where all the logic is done. Instead of posting excerpts from your system, please post a short reproducible code sample of iText code if you claim the problem is in iText and not in other parts of the system. Moreover, on looking up `ITextRenderer ` on the web you will see that it is a class from `flyingsaucer` library, so better retag and rename your question.

Comment: This would be an iText question if you used [iText 7: converting HTML to PDF](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) to convert HTML to PDF, but you don't. You use an old third party tool that isn't endorsed by iText Group. See also [Which languages are supported in pdfHTML?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/which-languages-are-supported-pdfhtml) Note: iText 7 is the only HTML to PDF library with support for Indic languages.